# How to switch off the move up position of slide menu?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to modify this sample code.  I want to stop the menu sliding up.  But not sure where to turn off that function.  Any expert can help?

http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sidebar-Sliding-Menu-Slidemenu.html

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    var SlideMenu = function(element, options) {
        this.element = null;
        this.options = null;
        this.init('slideMenu', element, options);
    };

    SlideMenu.VERSION = '0.1.2';
    SlideMenu.SLIDE_SPEED = 0.5;
    SlideMenu.DEFAULTS = {
        side: "right",
        panelDirection: "vertical",
        iconWidth: "",
        panelWidth: "",
        autoIconWidth: true,
        autoPanelWidth: true,
        initialized: false,
        enabled: true,
        show: false,
        top: "",
        bottom: ""
    };
    var CLASSES = {
        ACTIVE: "active",
        OPEN: "open",
        CLOSED: "closed",
    };
    var EVENTS = {
        OPENED: "slidemenu.openend",
        CLOSED: "slidemenu.closed",
        BEFORE_OPEN: "slidemenu.beforeOpen",
        BEFORE_CLOSE: "slidemenu.beforeClose"
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.init = function(type, element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.options = this.getOptions(options);

        if (this.options.initialized) {
            console.log("Menu is already initialized. Destroy the menu before trying to initialize again.");
            return;
        }
        if (this.$element.hasClass("left-side")) this.options.side = "left";

        if (document.readyState !== 'complete') $(document).on("ready", this.resize());
        else this.resize();
        var instance = this;
        $(window).resize(function(event) {
            SlideMenu.prototype.resize.apply(instance);
        });

        var top = 0;
        $(".menu-item", this.$element).each(function(index, element) {
            $(element).css("position", "absolute");
            $(element).attr("data-index", index);
            $(element).css("top", top + "px");
            top += $(element).height();
        });

        this.$element.off("click").on("click", ".menu-item", this, this.menuClick);
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.menuClick = function(event) {
        var instance = event.data;
        if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE)) { //Close this menu item since it's the only one open
            instance.close(event, instance);
        } else if ($(event.currentTarget).parents(".slide-menu").hasClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE)) { //Close open menu and move new menu into place
            instance.switchMenus(event, instance);
        } else { //Open the menu that was selected
            instance.openMenu(event, instance);
        }
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.getDefaults = function() {
        return SlideMenu.DEFAULTS;
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.getOptions = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({}, this.getDefaults(), this.$element.data(), options);
        if (options.iconWidth !== "") {
            options.autoIconWidth = false;
        }
        if (options.panelWidth !== "") {
            options.autoPanelWidth = false;
        }
        return options;
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.resize = function() {
        var changed = false;
        //Perform calculations
        var topOffset = 0;
        if (typeof(this.options.top) == "number") {
            topOffset = this.options.top;
            this.$element.css("top", this.options.top + "px");
        }
        var bottomOffset = 0;
        if (typeof(this.options.bottom) === "number") {
            bottomOffset = this.options.bottom;
        }
        var menuHeight = $(window).height() - topOffset - bottomOffset;
        if (menuHeight != this.$element.height()) {
            changed = true;
        }
        if (this.options.autoIconWidth && $(".menu-icon", this.$element).outerWidth(true) > this.options.iconWidth) {
            this.options.iconWidth = $(".menu-icon", this.$element).outerWidth(true);
            changed = true;
        }
        this.options.panelWidth = 250;
        this.options.width = this.options.panelWidth + this.options.iconWidth;
        //Init Once

        if (this.options.show === false) this.show();

        if (changed) {
            this.$element.width(this.options.width);
            this.$element.height(menuHeight).css("top", topOffset);
            if (this.options.side == "right") {
                var itemsLeft = -this.options.iconWidth - parseInt($(".menu-items", this.$element).css("border-left-width"));
                $(".menu-items", this.$element).css("left", itemsLeft + "px");
            } else {

            }
            $(".menu-close", this.$element).css("width", this.options.iconWidth + "px");
        }
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.openMenu = function(event, instance) {
        instance.$element.trigger(EVENTS.BEFORE_OPEN);
        instance.$element.addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        var left, leftBorder;

        var movement = {};
        console.log(instance.options.width);
        if (instance.options.side == "right") {
            leftBorder = parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("border-left-width"));
            left = parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left"));
            movement = {
                left: parseInt(-instance.options.width - left - leftBorder) + "px"
            };
        } else if (instance.options.side == "left") {
            left = parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left"));
            movement = {
                right: parseInt(-instance.options.width + instance.options.iconWidth) + "px"
            };
        }
        var optionObj = {
            duration: 250,
            complete: function() {
                if ($(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, instance.$element).css("top") != "0px") {
                    instance.reorder(function() {
                        instance.$element.trigger(EVENTS.OPENED);
                        instance.openPanel($(event.currentTarget));
                    });
                } else {
                    instance.$element.trigger(EVENTS.OPENED);
                    instance.openPanel($(event.currentTarget));
                }
            }
        };
        $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, instance.$element).animate(movement, optionObj);
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.switchMenus = function(event, instance) {
        instance.closePanel();
        var left, leftBorder;
        //Slide new menu out
        var movement = {};
        if (instance.options.side == "right") {
            leftBorder = parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("border-left-width"));
            left = parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left"));
            movement = {
                left: parseInt(-instance.options.width - left - leftBorder) + "px"
            };
        } else if (instance.options.side == "left") {
            left = parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left"));
            movement = {
                right: parseInt(-instance.options.width + instance.options.iconWidth) + "px"
            };
        }
        var switchOpts = {
            duration: 250,
            complete: function() {
                instance.reorder(function() {
                    instance.openPanel($(event.currentTarget).data("target"));
                });
            }
        };
        $(event.currentTarget).stop().animate(movement, switchOpts);
        //Slide current menu in
        movement = {};
        if (instance.options.side == "right") {
            movement = {
                left: "0px"
            };
        } else if (instance.options.side == "left") {
            movement = {
                right: "0px"
            };
        }
        $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, instance.$element).animate(movement, 250, function() {
            $(this).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        });
        $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, instance.$element).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.close = function(callback) {
        this.$element.trigger(EVENTS.BEFORE_CLOSE);
        var instance = this;
        var movement = {};
        if (instance.options.side == "right") {
            movement = {
                left: "0px"
            };
        } else if (this.options.side == "left") {
            movement = {
                right: "0px"
            };
        }
        this.closePanel();
        var closeOpts = {
            duration: 250,
            complete: function() {
                instance.$element.removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
                instance.$element.trigger(EVENTS.CLOSED);
                if (typeof(callback) == "function") callback();
                $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, instance.$element).removeClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
                //Move tiles back to their places
                instance.reorder();
            }
        };
        $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, instance.$element).stop().animate(movement, closeOpts);
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.openPanel = function(target) {
        $(target, this.$element).addClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
        if (this.options.panelDirection == "vertical") {
            $(".active .menu-body", this.$element).animate({
                height: this.$element.height() - $(".active .menu-header").height() + "px"
            }, 250, 'linear');
        } else if (this.options.panelDirection == "horizontal") {

        }
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.closePanel = function(callback) {
        var instance = this;
        var movement = {};
        var $panel = $(".active .menu-body", instance.$element);
        $panel.css("z-index", "-1");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $panel.css({
                "height": "0",
                "z-index": ""
            });
        }, 250);
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.open = function(target) {
        $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element).click();
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.hide = function(callback) {
        //Slide the menu out the side
        var instance = this;
        if (this.isOpen()) instance.close(
            function() {
                hideSlideMenu();
            }
        );
        else hideSlideMenu();

        function hideSlideMenu() {
            if (instance.options.side == "right") {
                $(".menu-items", instance.$element).animate({
                    left: "0px"
                }, 250);
            } else {
                $(".menu-items", instance.$element).animate({
                    left: -instance.options.width + "px"
                }, 250);
            }
            instance.options.show = false;
        }
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.show = function(callback) {
        if (this.options.show === true) return;
        var instance = this,
            animateOptions, itemsLeft;
        //Slide the menu in from the side
        if (parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("right")) === 0 || parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left")) === 0) {
            if (this.options.side == "right") {
                itemsLeft = -instance.options.iconWidth - parseInt($(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("border-left-width"));
                animateOptions = {
                    duration: 250,
                    complete: function() {
                        instance.options.show = true;
                        instance.resize();
                        if (typeof(callback) == "function") callback();
                    }
                };
                $(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left", "0px").animate({
                    left: itemsLeft + "px"
                }, animateOptions);
            } else {
                itemsLeft = -instance.options.width + instance.options.iconWidth;
                animateOptions = {
                    duration: 250,
                    complete: function() {
                        instance.options.show = true;
                        instance.resize();
                        if (typeof(callback) == "function") callback();
                    }
                };
                $(".menu-items", instance.$element).css("left", -instance.options.width + "px").animate({
                    left: itemsLeft + "px"
                }, animateOptions);
            }
        }
        instance.options.initialized = true;
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.addTab = function(args) {
        //Get ID from content
        var tab = $(args.tab);
        if ($(tab).hasClass("menu-item") === false) $(tab).addClass("menu-item");
        $(".menu-items", this.$element).append(tab);
        this.reorder();
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.removeTab = function(target) {
        $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element).replaceWith("");
        $(target, this.$element).replaceWith("");
        this.reorder();
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.hideTab = function(target) {
        if ($(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element).hasClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE)) {
            //If panel is open then close the menu
            var instance = this;
            this.close(function() {
                $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", instance.$element).hide();
            });
        } else {
            $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element).hide();
            //Rearrange tiles
            this.reorder();
        }
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.showTab = function(target) {
        $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element).show();
        //Rearrange tiles
        this.reorder();
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.changePosition = function(args) {
        var target = args.target;
        var position = args.position;
        var item = $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element);
        $(".menu-item[data-target='" + target + "']", this.$element).replaceWith("");
        if (position == 1) {
            $(".menu-items", this.$element).prepend(item);
        } else {
            $(".menu-item:nth-child(" + parseInt(position - 1) + ")", this.$element).after(item);
        }
        this.reorder();
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.reorder = function(callback) {
        var top = 0;
        if ($(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, this.$element).css("top") == "0px") {
            if (typeof(callback) === "function") callback();
        } else {
            if ($(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, this.$element).length > 0) {
                var animateOptions = {
                    duration: 250,
                    complete: function() {
                        if (typeof(callback) === "function") callback();
                    }
                };
                $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, this.$element).animate({
                    top: top + "px"
                }, animateOptions);
                top += $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE, this.$element).height();
            }
        }
        //If there is an open tab then move the first element below it
        if ($(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE).length) top = $(".menu-item." + CLASSES.ACTIVE).height();
        $(".menu-item:visible", this.$element).each(function(index, element) {
            if ($(element).hasClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE) === false) {
                $(element).animate({
                    top: top + "px"
                }, 250);
                top += $(element).height();
            }
        });
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.disable = function(target) {
        this.options.enabled = false;
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.enable = function(target) {
        this.options.enabled = true;
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.isOpen = function() {
        return this.$element.hasClass(CLASSES.ACTIVE);
    };

    SlideMenu.prototype.destroy = function() {
        this.$element.css("width", "").css("height", "").css("top", "");
        this.$element.find(".menu-items").css("left", "");
        this.$element.find(".menu-item").css("position", "").css("top", "").css("left", "");
        this.$element.find(".menu-close").css("width", "");
        delete this.options;
        delete this.$element;
    };

    function Plugin(option, args) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data('slidemenu');
            var options = typeof option == 'object' && option;

            if (!data) $this.data('slidemenu', (data = new SlideMenu(this, options)));
            if (typeof option == 'string') data[option](args);
        });
    }

    var old = $.fn.slidemenu;

    $.fn.slidemenu = Plugin;
    $.fn.slidemenu.Constructor = SlideMenu;

    // Slidemenu NO CONFLICT
    // ===================  
    $.fn.slidemenu.noConflict = function() {
        $.fn.slidemenu = old;
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: You have just pasted a huge chunk of code. No one in their right mind will go through that trying to find what you want to change. Do your best to slim the code down and edit your post.

Comment: Here is the demo screen, where when user clicks on the button, the selected button will move to the top.  How to disable this function?

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sidebar-Sliding-Menu-Slidemenu/